# Joining multiple data frames in one statement and selecting only required columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark DataFrames:

- `df1` with columns `(id, name, age)`
- `df2` with columns `(id, salary, city)`
- `df3` with columns `(name, dob)`

I want to join all of these Spark data frames using Python. This is the SQL statement I need to replicate.

SQL:

```python
select df1.*,df2.salary,df3.dob
from df1    
left join df2 on df1.id=df2.id    
left join df3 on df1.name=df3.name
```

I tried something that looks like below in Pyspark using python but I am receiving an error.

```python
joined_df = df1.join(df2,df1.id=df2.id,'left')\
               .join(df3,df1.name=df3.name)\
               .select(df1.(*),df2(name),df3(dob)
```

My question: Can we join all the three DataFrames in one go and select the required columns?

Comment: I need the answer in python not scala

Comment: `df1.(*)` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a SQL query that works, why not use `pyspark-sql`?

First use [`pyspark.sql.DataDrame.createOrReplaceTempView()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView) to register your DataFrame as a temporary table:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
df3.createOrReplaceTempView('df3')
```

Now you can access these DataFrames as tables with the names you provided in the argument to `createOrReplaceTempView()`. Use [`pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql) to execute your query:

```
query = "select df1.*, df2.salary, df3.dob " \
        "from df1 " \
        "left join df2 on df1.id=df2.id "\
        "left join df3 on df1.name=df3.name"

joined_df = spark.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `col` and `alias` to get the SQL-like syntax to work. Ensure your DataFrames are aliased:

```
df1 = df1.alias('df1')
df2 = df2.alias('df2')
df3 = df3.alias('df3')
```

Then the following should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

joined_df = df1.join(df2, col('df1.id') == col('df2.id'), 'left') \
.join(df3, col('df1.name') == col('df3.name'), 'left') \
.select('df1.*', 'df2.salary', 'df3.dob')
```

Comment: @pault thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my response accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you even need the aliases for `df2` and `df3` here. I haven't tested but I think the following should work: `joined_df = df1.alias('df1').join(df2, on='id', how='left').join(df3, on='name', how='left').select('df1.*', 'salary', 'dob')`

Comment: @pault thanks for that. I've learnt something new - will definitely try that out next opportunity I get.

Comment: @pault thanks for your answer, it worked like charm, however I was wondering whether we can groupby and sum fields and select only required fields in one go, can you use same example and group by name, age and get max(dob) and select only columns name,age,maxdob in one go

Comment: @bobby1985 there are a number of posts on StackOverflow that show how to do this. Search for Window functions or aggregate functions. If those don't solve your issue, please ask a new question.